# Polar Form of a Matrix (functional calculus )

Tags: functional-analysis, functional-calculus

Let $T=
    \begin{pmatrix}
    1 & 1  \\
    0 & 0  \\
    \end{pmatrix}
$.

Find the polar form of $T= W|T|$, where $|T|= \sqrt{T^*T}$, and $W$ is unitary.

I was able to find

$|T|=
    \begin{pmatrix}
    \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} &  \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}  \\
    \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} &  \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}  \\
    \end{pmatrix}
$.

But I'm having trouble finding $W$, since $|T|$ here is not invertible.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Note that you're just trying to find a unitary $U$ that sends $(1/\sqrt{2}, 1/\sqrt{2})$ to $(1,0).$  It doesn't matter what $U$ does to the rest of the space (as long as it is unitary). There is no uniqueness of $U$ when $T$ is not invertible.  You may think of a rotation that does the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The matrix
$$
W = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1
\\
1 & -1
\end{pmatrix}
$$
solves your equation.

Comment: May I ask how you got the matrix?

Comment: In this case, by inspection, in general $W = U V^*$ where $V$ diagonalises $T^* T$ and $U$ diagonalises $T T^*$. $U,V$ may be obtained directly from singular value decomposition.